# Starter Clicking sound

Tags: starter

I have a 2004 Honda Accord with a V-6.  My car radio, lights and everything work fine, but my starter seems to work intermittently. Sometimes I don't hear any click, sometimes its one, and sometimes it starts. It can go anywhere from taking 20+ key turns to get it to start or it'll start the 1st time could this be my starter? It sounds like a connection issue.

I have checked the connections at the battery and they are on the battery solid. The negative one was corroded, it seems to corrode a lot, we clean it off every 6 months.

Comment: Check the battery cable connections right at the battery - can you twist them on the terminals?  Are they corroded?

Answer (score 1):

Check the connections as the battery, the chassis ground, the starter solenoid (if external), and the starter. This would best be done with a voltage drop test.

If nothing show up on the voltage drop test ensure you are getting voltage to the signal wire (small wire) on the starter or external solenoid.

Finally if all that checks out it's most likely the starter solenoid, either the external one or the one attached to the starter. Some are only replaceable with the starter.